# SQL Update based on evaluations of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there was an easy way to use CASE and IF/ELSE statements in T-SQL to come up with a query that will compare a column `enrollment_date` between rows where the `course_id` is the same amongst instructors. Here is the context:

```
select u.user_id, cu.enrollment_date, cm.course_id from course_users cu
join course_main cm on cu.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
join users u on cu.users_pk1 = u.pk1
where cu.role = 'P' and cm.course_id like '%SP2014' and (cu.row_status = 0 or cu.row_status = 2)
order by course_id asc
```

This query returns a list of all of the instructor enrollments in courses and their enrollment dates. An example of the rows returned:

```
user_id         enrollment_date           course_id
dennismennis    2014-01-27 14:55:30.253    MATH-101
stevenspielberg 2014-01-27 14:55:30.413    MATH-102
lemmings        2014-01-27 14:55:30.300    MATH-103
johndoe         2014-01-27 14:55:24.750    ENGL-101
bobsmith        2014-01-28 14:55:24.790    ENGL-101
susysweet       2014-01-29 14:55:24.737    ENGL-101
```

What I need to be able to do is look at these rows, and compare the enrollment dates against rows ONLY where the `course_id` between a set of `user_ids` are the same. So for example I'd skip the first 3 instructor enrollments because they course_id isn't the same amongst them, so I don't have to worry about multiple enrollments into the same class. The comparison I want to look for is the most recent `enrollment_date` so `enrollment date greater than any other enrollment date that came before for the same course_id between these user_ids`

One other issue is that my select statement does not simply return 3 rows, right now as I have it written it returns 901 rows so I need to look through those results and then update things accordingly.

Essentially the query I'm looking for will provide the comparison required and then `update course_users set row_status = 2 where enrollment_date greater than any other enrollment date for the same course_id amongst other instructors.`

Thanks!

modified query based on answer below:

```
Merge course_users AS T
Using (
    Select max(cu.enrollment_date) as EnrollDate, cm.course_id from course_users cu
join course_main cm on cu.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
join users u on cu.users_pk1 = u.pk1
where cu.role = 'P' and cm.course_id like '%SP2014' group by cm.course_id
) As SRC ON SRC.Course_ID = T.crsmain_pk1 and SRC.EnrollDate != T.enrollment_date
WHEN MATCH 
THEN UPDATE SET T.row_status = 2;
```

Receive incorrect syntax at `MATCH`? Is it supposed to be `MATCHED`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "any other enrollment date that came before"?  What column specified this ordering?  It can't be the enrollment date, because that would be a tautology.

Comment: For clarification, what records above would you want to update?

Comment: The records above aren't shown in my select statement but I would be updating a column called cu.row_status(course_users table) based on the evaluation. What I mean by "any other enrollment date that came before" is, I'm looking for the most recent enrollment date amongst a group of instructors where the course_id is the same, and THEN, disabling the enrollments for any other enrollment date that came before the most recent one AND is also in the same course.

Comment: Would you mind posting some of the schema of the tables?  It will help me write some persuado-code.

Comment: Do these help? Schema for users, course_users, and course_main table

http://library.blackboard.com/ref/88b759da-a417-4b99-bd6d-e0d36daae457/tables/as_core/users.html

http://library.blackboard.com/ref/88b759da-a417-4b99-bd6d-e0d36daae457/tables/as_core/course_main.html

http://library.blackboard.com/ref/88b759da-a417-4b99-bd6d-e0d36daae457/tables/as_core/course_users.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to investigate leveraging the Merge function for performing this task.  This code is meant to give you an idea of where to go.  You are the expert on the schema, so you will be able to figure out what the course_id is in the course_users table.

```
Merge course_users AS T
Using (
    Select max(cu.enrollment_date) as EnrollDate, cm.course_id from cte group by course
) As SRC ON SRC.Course_ID = T.Course_ID and SRC.EnrollDate != T.enrollment_date
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.row_status = 2;
```

Here is a link to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) on the Merge function.

Comment: I modified the code with the correct schema information however I get an error about "incorrect syntax" at the MATCH statement. Check my question for the modification I made.

Comment: Was it supposed to be "WHEN MATCHED" not MATCH?

Comment: The query almost works but I need a condition to only update the row_status where the role = P, using my query disabled EVERY single user account(of course I'm doing this on a testing server with a back up). Any ideas?

Comment: The syntax is indeed `WHEN MATCHED`. You can add the `AND role=P` after the ON conditions of the SRC

Comment: @NickyvV would that be "WHEN MATCHED AND role=P" or would it go at the end of the SRC conditions "As SRC ON SRC.pk1 = T.crsmain_pk1 and SRC.EnrollDate != T.enrollment_date AND role=P" ?

Comment: The latter, so after `SRC ON...`

Comment: My bad about the "matched" statement.  That is the issue when in a hurry with persuado-code.  You can chain several conditions to each match.  So I would do WHEN MATCHED AND ROLE= 'P'.

Comment: Everything worked beautifully. Thank you both websch01ar and NickyvV